# A finitely generated locally finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

I've understood that there are finitely generated groups which are also locally finite groups (an infinite finitely generated group which has no subgroups of finite index that are no trivial), but I can't find an example so such group.

I would love if someone could point me to such an example

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood something, but a locally finite group (=LFG) is one in which any f.g. subgroup is finite, so if the LFG is itself finitely generated then it is finite...am I missing something? Your definition between parentheses seems to add to the LFG the condition of being *infinite* and f.g., but why would that be so?

Comment: He doesn't mean locally finite. There are infinite finitely generated (even finitely presented ) simple groups. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, now I see what he most probably meant

Comment: @tzoorp You seem to have a non-standard definition of locally finite. But you are looking for an example of an infinite finitely-generated group with no non-trivial subgroups of finite index. Is that correct?

Comment: @almagest yes, that is what I'm looking for.. so what is the standard definition for locally finite group? just out of curiosity

Comment: For a property $P$, a group $G$ is locally $P$ if all finitely generated subgroups of $G$ satisfy $P$. So a finitely generated locally $P$-group is itself a $P$-group. In particular, a finitely generated locally finite group is finite.